# How do fish persist in the upper parts of mountainous rivers with waterfalls?

Tags: ichthyology, limnology, biogeography

I was recently traveling in a remote mountain region and hiking alongside a very small river.
What caught my attention was the fish in the small ponds under the waterfalls.

These ponds were just a couple of square meters in size and each one housed between 5 and 10 fish.

The course (do you mean flow?) of the river combined with the waterfalls mean it was basically out of question that they could swim / jump upstream.

In such small mountainous rivers, how do fish remain in the upper parts over the course of hundreds of years.
I mean the size of the ponds and the amount of fish did not look to me like it could be sustainable for a population. And there should be the occasional one going down.

Are there examples or situations where the upstream population becomes extinct?

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! I edited your post, but please check to make sure I haven't changed your meaning. In your third paragraph you say that "... course of the river combined with ..." — did you mean flow. If not, can you clarify what it is about the river that makes you think it was impossible for fish to migrate upstream? Thanks!  

Comment: @tyersome "Course of a river" is a common term. It refers to the path the river takes, including the path traveled across the surface of the earth, elevation changes, flow changes as a river goes through shallow/wide or narrow/deep sections, rapids, etc.

Comment: things to consider 1. some fish are very good at getting upstream and some can even climb the rock behind a waterfall 2 a rivers course now is not what it has always been, just because there is a waterfall now does not mean there was always one.

Comment: @BryanKrause — I am familiar with that usage, but in the context of that sentence (using "combined with") it appeared to me that the OP might mean something different, which is why I requested clarification ...

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I'm not a native English speaker :) @Bryan Krause is right